# Prevent floating divs from breaking apart in a small window

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have three `div`s which are positioned side-by-side by using `float: left` on all three:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">...</div>
    <div id="center">...</div>
    <div id="right">...</div>
</div>
```

The left and the center `div`s have fixed widths, while the right `div` will have a variable width depending on its content.

The issue I'm having is that when I make my browser's window smaller than the combined width of the `div`s (and thus make the wrapper `div` too narrow) they break apart and no longer appear to be side-by-side.
I know that using static/absolute positioning will be an easy fix, but from my experience it is harder to maintain than using `float` and I would rather avoid it.

**Is there any way to fix this without switching to a different positioning technique?**

Comment: set a min-width on the wrapper. otherwise, no, not much you can do.

Comment: have you tried setting min-width for the wrapper div ?

Comment: @MarcB setting min-width wouldn't really help me since the size of the right div changes from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep the divs on the same row even if forces a scroll ball on the bottom? If so you can set a min-width: on the container div or the right div.

You could also use an @media rule in your style sheet to only give the right div a fixed width when the screen is below a certain size. Something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
 #div-right {  width:150px    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I want to force a scroll-bar if the width of the browser window is less than the combined width of the three `div`s. The problem is that because they are `float`-ed, they seemingly do not affect the size of the wrapper `div`.

Comment: did you try adding a min width to the container and right div?